# ASP.NET embedding internal pages within page with expired certificate C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am **very green** to developing a web front-end.

I wanted to create an eternally hosted site that will pull a collection of resources.

This is the scenario:

I want to "embed" pages within the web app. My thoughts, make the site called look exactly like it does originally, but keep the navigation header above. I have googled quite a bit to try and get a good direction in where to take this. From what I have found, iframe is the way to go.

The issues:
We host Dell Open manage Essentials on one of our servers. The only way to access this is through https://ome/. We currently do not have CA in place, therefore the certificate that is currently on the server is expired. This error is accurate due to the lack of a valid certificate.

My question:
1). Is iframe the right approach to this situation.
2). How do I bypass, or at least give the user the ability to continue to the embedded site? These sites are all internal.

Comment: You need to look up partial views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't decide for a user to display content for a site with an expired certificate.  The user has to accept that risk.  That's why the browsers now immediately flag pages with expired certificates and make it super-obvious.  There are few cases where you'd actually want to bypass this - so few, that the common browsers just don't make exceptions.

The VERY difficult way is to route your IFRAME url through a proxy that doesn't care about expired certs.

The less difficult way is to spend $50 on a certificate.  Or you can even get a free one (YMMV) at https://startssl.com (at your own risk.  I am unaffiliated.)

Comment: Is there a way to allow the user to continue within the iframe? Currently it just denies access.

Comment: Both Chrome and Firefox show an Advanced button (for now, this may change!)  If it's shown in the iframe, the user can click there to go through to the site.